# Connection between objects getting corrupted Python

Tags: python

My Program:

```
def load_people():
    f = open("a2_sample_set.txt", "r")
    people = []
    for x in f:
        name = x.split(":", 1)[0]
        first_name, last_name = [x.strip() for x in name.split(' ')]
        p = Person(first_name, last_name)
        people.append(p)
    f.seek(0)
    i = 0
    for x in f:
        p1 = people[i]
        i+=1
        friends = x.split(":", 1)[1]
        friend = [x.strip() for x in friends.split(',')]
        for fr in friend:
            for p2 in people:
                if fr == p2.get_name():
                    p1.add_friend(p2)
                    print(p1.get_name() + ":" + p2.get_name())
                    break
    f.close()
    for p in people:
        for f in p.get_friends():
            print(p.get_name() + ":" + f.get_name())
    return people
```

First print showing proper:

```
Gill Bates:Jodee Killam
Gill Bates:Natacha Osterhoudt
Gill Bates:Jom Tones
Gill Bates:Verdie Tong
Gill Bates:Ossie Digangi
Jom Tones:Marry Blakely
Jom Tones:Masako Miguel
Jom Tones:Gill Bates
Alton Justis:Verdie Tong
Alton Justis:Enrique Litz
```

Second print showing weird values:

```
Gill Bates:Jodee Killam
Gill Bates:Natacha Osterhoudt
Gill Bates:Jom Tones
Gill Bates:Verdie Tong
Gill Bates:Ossie Digangi
Gill Bates:Marry Blakely
Gill Bates:Masako Miguel
Gill Bates:Gill Bates
Gill Bates:Verdie Tong
Gill Bates:Enrique Litz
Gill Bates:Jettie Wilham
Gill Bates:Mikki Yerby
Gill Bates:Milo Charlebois
Gill Bates:Vicenta Seidel
Gill Bates:Levi Strasser
```

Please help me out, I am confused.

Comment: Please post the text file

Comment: What makes you think that the problem is actually in the fragment of code you posted?  I'd consider it more likely that something's wrong in the `.add_friend()` method - perhaps you have the friends list as a class attribute (rather than an instance attribute), so that only a single list exists.  (We request a [mcve] for a reason!)

Comment: You say "My Program:" and then proceed to post just a fragment of your program, one that doesn't show the class definition which is almost certainly the problem.